# How does the Hill Climbing algorithm work?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, hill-climbing

I'm learning Artificial Intelligence from a book, the book vaguely explains the code I'm about to post here, I assume because the author assumes everyone has experienced hill climbing algorithm before. The concept is rather straightforward, but I just don't understand some of the code below and I'd like someone to help me understand this algorithm a bit clearer before I move on.

I commented next to the parts that confuses me most, a summary of what these lines are doing would be very helpful to me.

```
int HillClimb::CalcNodeDist(Node* A, Node* B)
{
    int Horizontal = abs(A->_iX - B->_iX);
    int Vertical = abs(A->_iY - B->_iY);
    return(sqrt(pow(_iHorizontal, 2) + pow(_iVertical, 2)));
}

 void HillClimb::StartHillClimb()
{   
    BestDistance = VisitAllCities();
    int CurrentDistance = BestDistance;

    while (true)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int temp = VisitAllCities();
        while (i < Cities.size())
        {
            //Swapping the nodes
            Node* back = Cities.back();
            Cities[Cities.size() - 1] = Cities[i];
            Cities[i] = back; // Why swap last city with first?
            CurrentDistance = VisitAllCities(); // Why visit all nodes again?

            if (CurrentDistance < BestDistance) // What is this doing?
            {
                BestDistance = CurrentDistance; //???
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                back = Cities.back();
                Cities[Cities.size() - 1] = Cities[i];
                Cities[i] = back;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (CurrentDistance == temp)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

int HillClimb::VisitAllCities()
{
    int CurrentDistance = 0;    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Cities.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == Cities.size() - 1)//Check if last city, link back to first city
        {
            CurrentDistance += CalcNodeDist(Cities[i], Cities[0]);

        }
        else
        {
            CurrentDistance += CalcNodeDist(Cities[i], Cities[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return(CurrentDistance);
}
```

Also the book doesn't state what type of hill climb this is. I assume it's basic hill climb as it doesn't restart when it gets stuck?

Comment: It indeed only finds local minimum (we are looking for minimal distance). I would rename `VisitAllCities` by something like `ComputePathLengthAroundAllCities`. code swaps city with (arbitrary) the last city, if new path is shorter than previous, we record that one and reiterate the processus,else we rollback and test the next swap.

Comment: Wait, so it's sliding downwards? I thought the whole point of this algorithm is to go upwards?

Comment: You try to minimize the distance to visit all cities. and minimizing is similar to maximizing (as minimizing `cost` is maximize `-cost`).

Comment: can you please tell which book, as am fed up of code in Python that not helps a beginner like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, it does this in pseudo-code:

```
initialize an order of nodes (that is, a list) which represents a circle

do{
    find an element in the list so that switching it with the last element of the
    list results in a shorter length of the circle that is imposed by that list
}(until no such element could be found)
```

VisitAllCities is a helper that computes the length of that circle, CalcNodeDist is a helper that computes the distance between two nodes
the outer while loop is what I called do-until, the inner while loop iterates over all elements.

The `if (CurrentDistance < BestDistance)` part simply checks whether changing that list by swapping results in a smaller length, if so, update the distance, if not, undo that change.

Did I cover everything you wanted to know? Question about a particular part?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now and I feel confident moving forward from this point. :)

Comment: One last thing though, how does this exit the outer loop iterations?  if (CurrentDistance == temp)
        {
            break;
        }

Comment: Sure, that's the idea. A break command will break the innermost possible looping scope, which at this position is the outer loop. By the way, might be a good learning experience for you if you go through a run of the program by using a debugger, seeing which variables change when and how.